# Using Qt-DLL in Python

Tags: python, c++, qt, dll

I am creating a DLL which uses Qt. I need to access this DLL from Python.
Here is an example code:

deploydll.pro:

```
QT       += core gui \
        xml \
        declarative

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += console

TARGET = DeployDll

DEFINES += DEPLOY_LIBRARY

SOURCES += \
    deploydll.cpp

HEADERS += \
    deploydll.h
```

deploydll.h:

```
#ifndef DEPLOYDLL_H
#define DEPLOYDLL_H

#include <iostream>

#if defined DEPLOY_LIBRARY
#define DEPLOY_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DEPLOY_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DEPLOY_EXPORT DeployDll
{
public:
    DeployDll();
    bool showMessage();
};

#endif // DEPLOYDLL_H

#deploydll.cpp

#include "deploydll.h"

#include <functional>

#define NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>

QApplication* a = 0;
int* argc = 0;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HANDLE hDll, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    switch( dwReason )
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        argc = new int( 0 );
        QApplication* a = new QApplication( *argc, 0 );
        QtConcurrent::run( &QApplication::exec );
    }
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        if( argc != 0 )
        {
            delete argc;
            argc = 0;
        }

        if( a != 0 )
        {
            delete a;
            a = 0;
        }
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

DeployDll::DeployDll()
{
    std::cout << "Constructor called!\n";
}

bool DeployDll::showMessage()
{
    std::cout << "Method called!\n";

    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Method called!");
    msgBox.exec();

    return true;
}
```

Here is an example python code:

```
from ctypes import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Started main!"
    cdll.LoadLibrary("DeployDll")
```

I added the Qt platforms folder into the C:\python27-folder.
The generated DLL is in the folder of the python project.

If I use the DLL in a simple C++ program it works, but when I execute the python script I get the following error message:

```
Started main!
QApplication::exec: Must be called from the main thread
QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting
```

I am using Windows 7 64 Bit, Python 2.7.3 and Qt 5.2.1 with MSVC2012 64 Bit compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Meybe you should use QApplication::exec() in the main thread. Why are you use QtConcurrent::run?

Answer (score 0):

If you just call `QApplication::exec()` in the `DllMain` this would be blocking the main thread completely. So `QApplication::exec()` is wrapped by an asynchronous call of `QtConcurrent::run`.